# Archive MySQL data using PHP every week

Tags: php, mysql, archiving, mysql-backup

I have a MySQL DB that receives a lot of data from a source once every week on a certain day of the week at a given time (about 1.2million rows) and stores it in, lets call it, the "live" table.

I want to copy all the data from "live" table into an archive and truncate the live table to make space for the next "current data" that will come in the following week.

Can anyone suggest an efficient way of doing this. I am really trying to avoid  -- insert into archive_table select * from live --. I would like the ability to run this archiver using PHP so I cant use Maatkit. Any suggestions?

EDIT: Also, the archived data needs to be readily accessible. Since every insert is timestamped, if I want to look for the data from last month, I can just search for it in the archives

Comment: What about cron job which does mysqldump to a file that your PHP can pick up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sneaky way:

Don't copy records over.  That takes too long.

Instead, just rename the live table out of the way, and recreate:

```
RENAME TABLE live_table TO archive_table;
CREATE TABLE live_table (...);
```

It should be quite fast and painless.

EDIT: The method I described works best if you want an archive table per-rotation period. If you want to maintain a single archive table, might need to get trickier.   However, if you're just wanting to do ad-hoc queries on historical data,  you can probably just use UNION.

If you only wanted to save a few periods worth of data, you could do the rename thing a few times, in a manner similar to log rotation.  You could then define a view that UNIONs the archive tables into one big honkin' table.

EDIT2: If you want to maintain auto-increment stuff, you might hope to try:

```
RENAME TABLE live TO archive1; 
CREATE TABLE live (...); 
ALTER TABLE LIVE AUTO_INCREMENT = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM archive1);
```

but sadly, that won't work.  However, if you're driving the process with PHP, that's pretty easy to work around.

Comment: Could i do this to a live table thats maybe getting about 100 rows a second then move the renamed table to another database while the new table is still in the live database and not loose any inserts and will it start auto increment over, im just researching to do the right thing thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Write a script to run as a cron job to:

1. Dump the archive data from the "live" table (this is probably more efficient using mysqldump from a shell script)
2. Truncate the live table
3. Modify the INSERT statements in the dump file so that the table name references the archive table instead of the live table
4. Append the archive data to the archive table (again, could just import from dump file via shell script, e.g. mysql dbname < dumpfile.sql)

Comment: well the live table has an auto_increment (also the primary key) and dumping the data from live to a sql file, then truncating the live table will reset the auto_increment and then next archive insert will fail.

Comment: @Rohit - In step 3, remove the primary key from the insert statement and allow the archive table to assign one automatically.  Also, deleting rows does not affect the auto increment value of a table.  The only way to modify auto increment is DDL:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: Well I just tried it to make sure, TRUNCATE TABLE 'x' resets the auto_increment to 1

Answer (score 0):

This would depend on what you're doing with the data once you've archived it, but have you considered using MySQL replication?

You could set up another server as a replication slave, and once all the data gets replicated, do your delete or truncate with a `SET BIN-LOG 0` before it to avoid that statement also being replicated.

Comment: I have considered replication but another server is not an option at this time :(

Comment: Also, the archived data needs to be readily accessible. Since every insert is timestamped, if I want to look for the data from last month, I can just search for it

Comment: Not having a server to use is a bit of a showstopper there I must admit :) If you had it all going into one table though I don't think the serchability would be much of an issue unless I'm missing something.